# How to use the Index calculated using Factor Analysis in future surveys?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

I calculated an index using factor analysis from a survey data set. What I did is, I used exploratory factor analysis (PCA method) and derive 6 factors after varimax rotation. Now, using the factor scores of the 6 factors I calculated the index by summing up the factors multiplied by its weight:

```
index = weight1*factor1 + ...... + weight6*factor6

where weight is = % of variance explained/ %total variance explained
```

i got the procedure from this paper http://www.cup.ualberta.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/SEICUPWebsite_10April13.pdf

since this survey is done every year, my aim is to get a yearly comparison of the data.

Questions:
1. How will I be able to compare from year1 to year2 based on the index i calculated from year1? I plan to use this procedure: calculate the factor scores of each record in the dataset of year2 using the loadings from year1

```
factorscore1 = loading of variableA in year1 * value of variableA in year2 + ...+ loading of variableN in year1 * value of variableN in year2
```

The chosen variables are the variables with high loadings in year1 for factor1. Same procedure is followed for the other 5 factors.

For year 3 dataset:

factorscore1 = loading of variableA in year1 * value of variableA in year3 + ...+ loading of variableN in year1 * value of variableN in year3

Is this procedure valid?

2. Some questions are added and deleted. Will my procedure above still valid?

Thanks!

Comment: My comments pertain to the first half of your post.  I am having trouble imagining what value could be held by an index that is a combination of all components in an analysis (whether or not the index is weighted by the percent of variance explained by each component).  To be honest I do not see great merit in the paper you have relied upon.  Moreover, use of PCA and orthogonal rotation on *survey* data presents something of a red flag; though these are extremely common mistakes, they are almost certainly mistakes nonetheless. I recommend a statistical consultant, and I wish you well ~

Comment: Thanks rolando! ive read from one of the comments here in stackexchange that we cant add uncorrelated factors. may i know why we cant add the factors? in linear regression, we want the x's to be uncorrelated. The regression model is a sum of those x's with their weights.

Comment: The decision whether to combine factor scores is pretty distinct from the need for regression x's not to be too collinear.  If factor 1's score measures How Funny I Am, factor 2 How Careful I Am, factor 3 How Wealthy, etc., what could the sum of these scores possibly mean?  You could also look up literature on Semantic Differential; researchers don't add the scores of distinct topics when the scales run, say, Vegetable<-->Animal or Earth<-->Sky.